# How to get Pin<&mut T> out of Pin<Arc<Mutex<T>>>

Tags: rust, stream, future, rust-pin

I'm writing a stream adapter that requires a shared ownership of the stream.

Is it correct to store the stream (privately) in `Pin<Arc<Mutex<impl Stream>>>`?

How can I call `poll_next(self: Pin<&mut Stream>` on the stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mutex` does not have what is called *structural pinning*, which is described in the [`std::pin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/index.html?search=#projections-and-structural-pinning) module documentation:

> It turns out that it is actually up to the author of the data structure to decide whether the pinned projection for a particular field turns `Pin<&mut Struct>` into `Pin<&mut Field>` or `&mut Field`. [...] As the author of a data structure you get to decide for each field whether pinning "propagates" to this field or not. **Pinning that propagates is also called "structural", because it follows the structure of the type**.

`Mutex<T>` does not have structural pinning because the pinned-ness of the struct (the `Mutex`) does not propagate to the field (the `T`) -- it *is* safe to get an unpinned `&mut T` from a `Pin<&mut Mutex<T>>` (i.e., by using `Deref` instead of `DerefMut` and locking the mutex), even if `T` and `Mutex<T>` are `!Unpin`.

In order to turn this `&mut T` into a `Pin<&mut T>`, you have to make another layer of unchecked guarantee, using `unsafe` and `Pin::new_unchecked`, to prove that the `T` *itself* is never moved. This seems to defeat the purpose of the "outer" `Pin`.

Depending on what your data structures allow, you might consider one of these options:

- writing a wrapper for `Arc<Mutex>` that pins the contents of the `Mutex` when accessed through a `Pin` (you couldn't implement `Deref`, but you could write methods that returned `MutexGuard`s and did the `Pin`-wrapping internally)
- simply pushing the shared mutability inside the type that implements `Stream`, if your data structure allows it.